# Convert string data to dictionary inside list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

From a script, I am getting data like that is given below.

```
Neha, 30,A
Monika ,22,B
Anni,33,C
```

I want to convert this data in a given way that is given below.

```
[{'name':Neha,'age':30,'grade':A},{'name':Monika,'age':22,'grade':B},{'name':Anni,'age':33,'grade':c}]
```

Can anyone please help me to get the data in this way any suggestion . Thanks in advance

Comment: where are you running into difficulties? you can use the `csv` module to read your data conveniently into columns and then it's just a simple loop

Comment: See [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and make a code attempt.  Post that code if you have issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your solution

```
s = """Neha,30,A
Monika,22,B
Anni,33,C"""

# print(s.split('\n'))

l = []

s = s.split('\n')

for i in s:
    # print(i)
    temp = i.split(',')
    # print(temp)
    d = {}
    d['name'] = temp[0]
    d['age'] = temp[1]
    d['grade'] = temp[2]
    l.append(d)
print(l)
```